# Can VSCode extension API funtion provideCompletionItems() trigger from multiple trigger characters?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am writing an extension to provide auto completion results for the Data Format Description Language (https://daffodil.apache.org/docs/dfdl/), that is based in XML. I am using the VScode extension API function provideCompletionItems. I have a number of Completion items that are attributes. Since attributes can be combined on a single line ex:

```
<xs:element name="RGBA_Value" type="xs:hexBinary" dfdl:lengthKind="explicit" dfdl:lengthUnits="bytes" dfdl:length="4" />
```

or separated by linefeeds:

```
<xs:element name="RGBA_Value"
type="xs:hexBinary"
dfdl:lengthKind="explicit"
dfdl:lengthUnits="bytes"
dfdl:length="4" />
```

I am using the characters ' ' (space) and '\n' (linefeed) as the trigger to the provideCompletionItems trigger which is defined as a String array. I tried various ways to try to combine the characters in a string array but have not been successful. As a result I have created two provideCompletionItems functions that are mostly identical, one with a ' ' (space) trigger and one with a '\n' (linefeed) trigger. Both functions contain the same 21 completion Item definitions. I am trying to find a solution that doesn't require the use of duplicate completion items. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

@Mark I changed my code based on your suggestion, Here's an abbreviated version:

```
    const elementDfdlAttributeProvider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(
        'plaintext',
        {
            provideCompletionItems(document: vscode.TextDocument, position: vscode.Position) {
                const wholeLine = document.lineAt(position).text.substr(0, position.character);
                console.log('in elementspacetrigger: ' + wholeLine);
                if(wholeLine.includes('"{')) {
                    return undefined;                   
                }
                const dfdlDefineFormat = new vscode.CompletionItem("dfdl:defineFormat");
                dfdlDefineFormat.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString('<dfdl:defineFormat name="$1" >\n\t$2\n</dfdl:defineFormat>\n$0');
                dfdlDefineFormat.documentation = new vscode.MarkdownString("dfdl format name and configuration");
            
                const dfdlDefineEscape = new vscode.CompletionItem('dfdl:defineEscapeScheme');
                dfdlDefineEscape.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString('<dfdl:defineEscapeScheme name=$1 >\n\t$0,/dfdl:defineEscapeScheme>\n');
                dfdlDefineEscape.documentation = new vscode.MarkdownString("dfdl escape character definition");
.
.
.
                const dfdlOutputNewLine = new vscode.CompletionItem('dfdl:outputNewLine=');
                dfdlOutputNewLine.insertText = new vscode.SnippetString("dfdl:outputNewLine=\"${1|%CR,%LF,%CR%LF,%NEL,%LS|}\"$0");
                dfdlOutputNewLine.documentation = new vscode.MarkdownString("Specifies the character or characters that are used to replace the %NL; character class entity during unparse");
    
                //const wholeLine = document.lineAt(position).text.substr(0, position.character);
                if (wholeLine.includes('<xs:element name="') || (wholeLine.includes('<xs:element ref="'))) {
                    return [
                      xmlType,
                        minOccurs,
                        maxOccurs,
                        dfdlOccursCount,
                        dfdlOccursCountKind,
                        dfdlLength,
                        dfdlLengthKind,
                        dfdlLengthUnits,
                        dfdlLengthPattern,
                        xmlEncoding,
                        dfdlInputValueCalc,
                        dfdlOutputValueCalc,
                        dfdlAlignment,
                        dfdlAlignmentUnits,
                        dfdlTerminator,
                        dfdlOutputNewLine,
                    ];
                }
            }
        },

        ' ', '\n' // triggered whenever  ' ' or '\n' is typed
    );
```

The completion function works for a space character, but not a new line/linefeed. Maybe VSCode doesn't like the '\n'?

But if I remove the ' ' and just leave the '\n', that does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't an array.  This works for me:

`'"', '$'  // trigger intellisense/completion`

```js
const configCompletionProvider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider (
      { pattern: '**/keybindings.json' },     // your pattern here
      {
        provideCompletionItems(document, position) {}
      },
      '"', '$'
)
```

With both `"` and `$` triggering intellisense.

It is confusing that the signature for the trigger characters is :

`...triggerCharacters: string[]`

but I think it means that if you have an **array** of trigger characters you could use it like this:

`...['.', '"']`  which is equivalent to `'.', '"'`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I changed my code based on your suggestion, but it didn't work for me. I updated my original question to include the modified code block.

Comment: I am using it on a couple of extensions so you have another issue.  But they do work individually in two different `regisiter CompletionItemProvider`'s?

Comment: Yes, they work individually, when I have each one in a separate  registerCompletionItemProvider. But I can't get them to work in a single in a single instance.  I will try changing the '\n' to '.' to see if the new line character is causing the problem.

Comment: Actually your solution does work, I did have a different problem with my if statement before the return of the completion items.  The logic in the two registerCompletionItemProvider functions was slightly different.  When I combined the logic your suggestion above did work.  Thanks for the initial reply and the follow up! :)